How can we enable 'Industry Integration Solutions' in Salesforce org to access 'Integrations Setup' as per Salesforce documentation?
Currently, it's not visible in our org. Need assistance on enabling this feature. Thanks!
We are following the below document.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connect_to_mulesoft_instance.htm&type=5
From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter Integrations, and then    expand Integrations. Expand Industry Integration Solutions, and then select Integrations Setup.  We could not see  Industry Integration   Solutions, option available in our Salesforce org.
Please help with  the way to enable this option

kindly note to access Industry Integrations Solutions require a "MuleSoft Anypoint Platform license".
Kindly refer below article for same:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.access_integrations.htm&type=5

We have the license already in place
